# Instagram image url are not opening. Its giving error "Access denied". There are many of users. How to restore all images?

Tags: javascript, instagram, imageurl

I have hundreds of user and image links worked properly till yesterday then it starts giving "[acccess denied](https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/18444591_1175249269246249_8152849668800249856_n.jpg)" message. My app is live already and approximately 1500 images is from instagram. What can i do now?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and really, we can not wait for Instagram solution because we are in production and these error were generating a big UX error

I was trying to send the bug to instagram team, but it wasn't possible.

So, my recomendation is regenerate the images url with instagram oembed (http://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=${instagramPost}) and replace the new image url. I ran a migration into my DB and with this i solved the problem.